# content cutoff, no scroll (specific situation)

Tags: html, css

I am having some trouble where my content is cutoff (when window is resized) with no option to scroll down. I am also using a background that is not included here, but I think even with the black background, I get the same error. What must I do in order to allow scrolling here? I will also upload a second question regarding overlapping content when using the 'relative' feature to place my content which I am also struggling with. In this case, I attempted to structure the page without the use of relative, is my method a "good" way to do this?

note: I only started html/css 2 days ago after watching a YouTube series, so please excuse how bad I am at this :)

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

body {
 position: fixed;
 background: black;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: Open Sans;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

h1 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#aboutus {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 15%;
}

#imageback {
 content: "";
 display:block;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: url('../images/ariana.jpg');
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 opacity: 0.4;
 z-index: -2;
}

body div p {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.divcenter {
 text-align: justify;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 50%;
}















/*Some Fade Stuff (Can be shortened with Jquery)*/

.fadeImage {
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 3s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 3s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 3s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 3s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 0.4; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 0.4; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 0.4; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 0.4; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 0.4; }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>About Us</title>
  <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link href="about.html" rel="alternate" hreflang="en"/>
  <link href="about_pt.html" rel="alternate" hreflang="pt"/>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="imageback" class="fadeImage"></div>

  <header id="aboutus">
   <h1>About Us</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="divcenter">
   <p>
    this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text
   </p>
  </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tryed using your browser's inspector to see what is going wrong? See [Usign devtools as codeschool](http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/)

Comment: This looks like it will be very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `position: fixed;` from body in css, you basically cannot have the scroll bar on a `position:fixed` element

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

body {
 background: black;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: Open Sans;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}

h1 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#aboutus {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 15%;
}

#imageback {
 content: "";
 display:block;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: url('../images/ariana.jpg');
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 opacity: 0.4;
 z-index: -2;
}

body div p {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.divcenter {
 text-align: justify;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 50%;
}















/*Some Fade Stuff (Can be shortened with Jquery)*/

.fadeImage {
    -webkit-animation: fadein 3s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 3s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 3s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 3s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 3s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 0.4; }
}

/* Firefox < 16 */
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 0.4; }
}

/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 0.4; }
}

/* Internet Explorer */
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 0.4; }
}

/* Opera < 12.1 */
@-o-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 0.4; }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>About Us</title>
  <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link href="about.html" rel="alternate" hreflang="en"/>
  <link href="about_pt.html" rel="alternate" hreflang="pt"/>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="imageback" class="fadeImage"></div>

  <header id="aboutus">
   <h1>About Us</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="divcenter">
   <p>
    this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text this is just really long text
   </p>
  </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it! I then changed the width setting from a percentage to a fixed value under the .divcenter class so that I could get a horizontal scroll going as well. Any comments regarding the structure of the page? Is it correct to use the margin to place my elements where I want?